# Method returning with undefined value

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise

I have a method methFirst which is calling another method methSecond, but the problem is that methFirst is getting returned without waiting for methSecond to complete execution -

**main method**

```
methMain() {
    var result = methFirst();
    console.log(result); //undefined
}
```

**first method**

```
methFirst(obj) {
    methSecond(obj).then((result) => {
        return result;
    )};
}
```

**second method**

```
methSecond(obj){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if(obj == null) {
            resolve(true);
        }
    )};
}
```

I understand one way of doing this is returning a promise from methFirst but I do want to use it, any help would be appropriated.

Comment: Your `firstMethod` does not  `return` anything?

Comment: There is no way around promises. You have to use them. You cannot make it return synchronously (that's not what promises do).

Comment: Yes please let me know how can I handle that

Comment: Write `methMain() { firstMethod().then(function(result) { console.log(result); }); }` and `function firstMethod() { return secondMethod(); }`

Comment: is it possible any how by not using promise at all and removing it from `methSecond()` also ?

Comment: Well obviously in your example you could just write `function methSecond(obj) { if(obj == null) return true; }` in your example, but I understood you wanted to do something asynchronous - and no, promises are your best bet then.